# Who runs Email-to-Case

Tags: debugging, email2case, debug-logs

I am trying to debug the case trigger when I create a case via Email-to-Case. But I don´t know which user run the trigger. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the **Support Setting** and look for "**Automated Case user**" that user is used for Email-to-Case
[image]